# Toast "sending message to a Handler on a dead thread"

Tags: android

I'm trying to display a simple message via Toast, and am getting a RunTime Exception "sending message to a Handler on a dead thread". The class that is trying to show the Toast message extends IntentService. The class (C2DMReceiver) actually comes from the ChromeToPhone example for C2DM. Here is the method:

```
/**
 * Called when a cloud message has been received.
 */
@Override
public void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "A message notification has occured with the cloud.");

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Showing toast message of the broadcast...");
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Some text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Sending notification of the broadcast...");
        LauncherUtils.generateNotification(this, "this is where the text would go.", "Broadcast", intent);

    }
}
```

I assumed since the class extends IntentService that it would be possible to request a simple Toast message from here in this manner. Isn't this correct?

Answer (score 28):

This is due to a bug in AsyncTask in the Android framework. AsyncTask.java has the following code:

```
private static final InternalHandler sHandler = new InternalHandler();
```

It expects this to be initialized on the main thread, but that is not guaranteed since it will be initialized on whichever thread happens to cause the class to run its static initializers. I reproduced this issue where the Handler references a worker thread.

A common pattern that causes this to happen is using the class IntentService. The C2DM sample code does this.

A simple workaround is to add the following code to the application's onCreate method:

```
Class.forName("android.os.AsyncTask");
```

This will force AsyncTask to be initialized in the main thread. I filed a bug on this in the android bug database. See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20915.

Comment: I did this and it didn't help even a bit. Always when it received a c2dm notification, it logs the same exception.

Answer (score 24):

```
public class NetworkService extends IntentService {
    Handler mMainThreadHandler = null;

    public NetworkService() {
        super(NetworkService.class.getName());

        mMainThreadHandler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg) {
        System.out.printf("Network service intent handling: %s\n", arg.toString());
        mMainThreadHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BusyBox updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: As [Jonathan Perlow stated in his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7818794/1208581), there is a bug in the Android Framework, which causes a Toast, which is not created in the main thread, to run in a Handler, which is not attached to the main thread. By creating `mMainThreadHandler` on the main thread (in the constructor), we make sure the Toast runs in the main thread. That way we work around the bug.

Answer (score 12):

Another way to accomplish toasting messages in the main thread from the background is to use a small utility method for this. The trick is to create a handler that is attached to the looper of the main thread (Looper.getMainLooper()).

```
public class ToastUtils {

    public static void showToastInUiThread(final Context ctx,
        final int stringRes) {

        Handler mainThread = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        mainThread.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, ctx.getString(stringRes), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
       });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must display a toast from the main thread or it will not display to the screen.  The handler executes from the thread it was created in.  If you create your handler in onCreate of your intentservice it should work as intended when you send your message.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, since there is no direct reference to the handler from the toast object. I've implemented the onCreate method, but still getting dead thread exception. What is the proper way to create a handler in this situation? This is my onCreate, with protected Handler handler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        handler = new Handler()  
        {  
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)  
          {
              Log.i(LOG_TAG, "In handleMessage...");
          }  
        };  
    }

Answer (score 0):

The onMessage method was not called on Main Thread.

So you need to make a new Handler.

Apply this code:

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService
{
   Handler handler;
   public GCMIntentService()
   {
      handler = new Handler();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run your code on the ui thread like this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    try {
  //YOUR CODE
  } catch (Exception e) {
   Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
  }
 }
});
```

This should work fine